# JavaFx scaling at runtime

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

[image]

my screens scale well at the preview of scenebuilder:

[image]

but do not likewise at runtime...

[image]

This is the controller class for the FXML:

```
public class SelectionScreenController implements Initializable, 
ControlledScreen {

@FXML
ToggleGroup rbgSelection;
@FXML
RadioButton radHazopEaXls;
@FXML
RadioButton radHaraEaXls;
@FXML
RadioButton radHaraXlsEa;
@FXML
RadioButton radHazopXlsEa;
@FXML
RadioButton radFmeaEaXls;
@FXML
RadioButton radFmeaXlsEa;

ScreensController myController;


@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    SafetyDataExchange.primaryStage.sizeToScene();
}

public void setScreenParent(ScreensController screenParent) {
    myController = screenParent;
}

@FXML
private void goToNextScreen(ActionEvent event) {

    if (rbgSelection.getSelectedToggle().equals(radHaraEaXls)) {
        myController.setScreen(SafetyDataExchange.screen2ID);
        SafetyDataExchange.primaryStage.sizeToScene();      
    } else if (rbgSelection.getSelectedToggle().equals(radHaraXlsEa)) {
        myController.setScreen(SafetyDataExchange.screen3ID);
        SafetyDataExchange.primaryStage.sizeToScene();
    } else if (rbgSelection.getSelectedToggle().equals(radHazopEaXls)) {
        myController.setScreen(SafetyDataExchange.screen4ID);
        SafetyDataExchange.primaryStage.sizeToScene();
    } 

}
}
```

This is the FXML:

```
    <BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" 
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
    fx:controller="at.v2c2.safetydataexchange.gui.SelectionScreenController">
   <center>
      <VBox spacing="10.0">
         <children>
            <GridPane VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
              <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" 
    prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" 
    prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" 
    prefWidth="100.0" />
              </columnConstraints>
              <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                <RowConstraints vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                <RowConstraints vgrow="ALWAYS" />
              </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <Label text="HAZOP" />
                  <Label text="FMEA" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <RadioButton id="radHaraEaXls" fx:id="radHaraEaXls" 
    mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" text="EA-&gt;XLS" 
    GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                     <toggleGroup>
                        <ToggleGroup fx:id="rbgSelection" />
                     </toggleGroup>
                  </RadioButton>
                  <RadioButton id="radFmeaEaXls" fx:id="radFmeaEaXls" 
    mnemonicParsing="false" text="EA-&gt;XLS" toggleGroup="$rbgSelection" 
    GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <RadioButton id="radHazopXlsEa" fx:id="radHazopXlsEa" 
    mnemonicParsing="false" text="XLS-&gt;EA" toggleGroup="$rbgSelection" 
    GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
                  <RadioButton id="radFmeaXlsEa" fx:id="radFmeaXlsEa" 
    mnemonicParsing="false" text="XLS-&gt;EA" toggleGroup="$rbgSelection" 
    GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="HARA" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <RadioButton id="radHazopEaXls" fx:id="radHazopEaXls" 
    mnemonicParsing="false" text="EA-&gt;XLS" toggleGroup="$rbgSelection" 
    GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                  <RadioButton id="radHaraXlsEa" fx:id="radHaraXlsEa" 
    mnemonicParsing="false" text="XLS-&gt;EA (csv)" toggleGroup="$rbgSelection" 
    GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
               </children>
            </GridPane>
          <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#goToNextScreen" text="Next" 
    />
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
         </padding>
      </VBox>
    </center>
    <top>
      <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Exit" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Log">
               <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Toggle Hide/Show" />
               </items>
            </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
    </top>
    </BorderPane>
```

Also refreshing the project in Eclipse did not help.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It's almost impossible to say without knowing what you're doing. Please edit your question to include your FXML, or provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm still facing this annoying problem. At preview, the scenes are scaled, i.e. adapted in size, but at runtime, the controls just stay still...